# React app not displaying on GitHub Pages after successful deployment

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, web-hosting

Code is deployed, but react app is not showing on GitHub pages

I deployed the React App to GitHub Pages using gh-pages, but it's not showing anything.
Here is the link to the hosted repo: [text](https://smriti-sk.github.io/Expense-Tracker-App)/

Console output: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Please tell what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript file can be found at the following URL: https://smriti-sk.github.io/Expense-Tracker-App/static/js/main.fe27c528.js. However, the script tag `<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.fe27c528.js"></script>` suggests that the file is located at https://smriti-sk.github.io/static/js/main.fe27c528.js.

I would suggest

1. remove the "Expense-Tracker-App" folder from the repository
2. or change your path to /Expense-Tracker-App/static/js/main.fe27c528.js